# Data method :delete not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, ujs

I have the following code:

```
  <% @groups.each do |group| %>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" data-method="destroy" data-confirm="Sure?" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
         </button> 
   <% end %>
```

And in my controller:

```
 def destroy
   @group = Group.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|  
   if @result = @group.destroy  
    format.html
    format.js        
  else  
    format.html 
    format.js
  end  
 end  
end
```

However, it is not triggering even the confirmation.  I've looked at the API regarding UJS, as well as other posts on SO, however, I'm cannot figure out what *I* am doing wrong here.

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using `data-method="destroy"`, not `data-method="delete"`...

Comment: I get the same results with `data-method="delete"` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's how I fixed it:

First, I made sure all my resources were defined in the `routes` file.

`resources :groups`

Second, this is how I figured out the `link_to` method:

```
<%= link_to group, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :remote => true do %>
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button won't trigger the form submission, So you have to change it to a tag.